# Jquery ajax not working in laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5.6

In `assets/js/bootstrap.js` I have:

```
window._ = require('lodash');

window.Popper = require('popper.js/dist/umd/popper');

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery/dist/jquery.slim');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

My package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.12.6",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    }
```

So I guess for `ajax` you need `jquery` not `jquery slim`.

So how do I get only jquery and make laravel 5.6 use jquery instead of the slim version.

Answer (score 1):

Simply include `jQuery` instead of `jQuery slim`:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```